# Customize date format

Tags: ubuntu-mate, dconf

When I use Dconf-Editor to customize my date format, I get this.

[image]

Comment: Did you run `dconf-editor` with `sudo`? If so, what happens if you run it *without* `sudo`?

Comment: @ pomsky Same thing with or without sudo.